# Verifying resultant of two plots

Tags: c++, plot, benchmarking

In one of our experiments, we plotted a graph of Program runtime for different values of a variable, say `x` cnad call it plot1 . We believe that the program runtime is directly proportional to a variable, say `a` and inversely proportional to `b`. Therefore, we also plotted graphs for `a` and `b`, against x, and call them plot2 and plot3.

To verify that no other factor is involved, we want to somehow combine plots2 and plots3, such that what we get is close to plot1. I was thinking of plotting `a/b`, and trying binary search to find the constant `k`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my understanding of your problem is right, but:

We have a program that takes one input x and gives us a number (it's runtime) T(x).
Also, we have two other functions, a(x)>=0 and b(x)>0. Then there exist constants f,g, so that T(x)~f*a(x), T(x)~g/b(x).
We have functions a(x) and b(x) which are easily computable. Also, we can compute T(x) for some values of x, but this calculation is rather expensive. We want to build the estimate F : T(x)=F(a(x),b(x)).
It is important that both dependencies T(x)~f*a(x) and T(x)~g/b(x) are not exact (otherwise we could just measure T(1000), take f=T(1000)/a(1000) and have formula for T(x)).

As a general note, when searching for parameters it is a good idea to convert the expression so that it becomes linear to the relation of the parameters (this way we can use least squares method).
I would be looking for F in form F(a,b)=exp(C)*a^(k+1)*b^(k).
This assumes relation

```
ln(T(x)) ~ C+(k+1)*ln(a(x))+k*ln(b(x))
```

Or, after grouping,

```
ln(T(x))-ln(a(x)) ~ k*[ln(a(x))+ln(b(x))]+C
```

Now we measure T(x) for some values of x, build points (u,v): u=ln(T(x))-ln(a(x)), v=ln(a(x))+ln(b(x)) and try to find variables k,C, so that line u=k*v+C lies closest to points built (by linear squares or any other method). If k is very close to 0 or -1, that would mean that either f*a or g/b approximation is much more precise and the other one should be discarded.

**P.S.** Could be a good idea to choose values x for measuring T(x) so that ln(a(x))+ln(b(x)) varies as much as possible.